# DBPedia missing important smartphones

Tags: dbpedia

I could see DBPedia is missing very important mobile phone list. They exist in Wikipedia but not in DBPedia, e.g. OnePlus series, Micromax Yureka , Moto g4

I'm refering this link: http://live.dbpedia.org/page/Smartphone

Does it mean that it is not yet ready to be used for critical usage - say a customer related project?

Comment: Shouldn't you ask this question at DBPedia?

Comment: So if I have a doubt in Java should I mail oracle inc directly?

Comment: Data quality depends on the effort *you* are willing put into this. An alternative strategy would be to search for smartphone manufacturers, and then (for each of them) for their products, maybe with a SPARQL query.

Comment: Yes, DBPedia, being updated once per 6 months is definitely not ready for "critical usage"  - it would have been all too easy otherwise, no?

Comment: Wikidata might be more up-to-date.

Answer (score 3):

DBpedia (http://dbpedia.org/sparql) holds a static dataset, updated in batches roughly every 6-12 months.  Changes made on Wikipedia will eventually show up here.

DBpedia-Live (http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql) holds a dynamic dataset, updated from the Wikipedia firehose on a near-constant basis.  Changes made on Wikipedia generally show up here within hours if not seconds.

Wikipedia (and hence, derived DBpedia and DBpedia-Live) data is messy, and often lacks the specific detail you want, especially in the structured data block. For instance, the [YU Yureka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YU_Yureka) (not the "Micromax Yureka") does not have a **Type: Smartphone** entry, unlike, for instance, the [Xiaomi Mi 2S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaomi_Mi_2S).

The solution to your complaint is to update Wikipedia content, and then wait for DBpedia-Live to pick up your changes.